# jQuery fadeout page bug on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I'm using jQuery to fade my pages out (for a smooth transition) throughout my site. I'm using code outlined in a different stack exchange question (see below). It works great on all browsers on desktop. However, in mobile safari, there's a bug I don't understand. When I click the back button, nothing shows up, just a blank white screen, and it must be reloaded to show content. Does anyone know what's going on here?

```
// delegate all clicks on "a" tag (links)
$(document).on("click", "a", function () {

// get the href attribute
var newUrl = $(this).attr("href");

// veryfy if the new url exists or is a hash
if (!newUrl || newUrl[0] === "#") {
    // set that hash
    location.hash = newUrl;
    return;
}

// now, fadeout the html (whole page)
$("html").fadeOut(function () {
    // when the animation is complete, set the new location
    location = newUrl;
});

// prevent the default browser behavior.
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Plug your iPhone into your computer and use the debugger to step through and see what's happening. I speculate that location or location.hash isn't working in mobile Safari how you are expecting.  (I've previously had problems with location hashes in mobile Safari.)